# About implement of local notifications in apple watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilocalnotification, apple-watch

I want to implement local notifications in apple watch. As I read many articles I came to know that notifications will appear in both iPhone and apple watch when they are paired. So can any one suggest me while implementing local notifications, in which class I have to write the code means iPhone's related class or watch related class? and please suggest me how to test that notifications in simulator?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the how-to-ask, to make sure your issue can be easily understood and is consequently well received! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no way to specifically target local notifications to the Apple Watch. Your main app, running on the phone, issues local notifications. iOS determines whether the notification should be delivered to the phone only or the phone and the watch based on whether the user is actively using the phone, it's lock state and so on.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for ur reply, while implementing notifications for watch ,we will get iPhone related classes and watch extension classes in Xcode. So can you please suggest me where should i write the code to show notifications for watch ?